# Positioning tikz arrows to coordinates inside tabulars

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, beamer, positioning, arrows

I need to create a slide with multiple tabulars and use arrow to point to elements inside those tabulars.

However, I'm having trouble to specify where tabulars, texts and arrows should appear. How can I do this?

My minimal non-working example follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}              % only frames
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning,matrix}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[remember picture] \node[coordinate] (#1) {#1};}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Example}
  \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\tikzmark{col1}
      \begin{tabular}{|c|}\hline
          \tikzmark{elem1}2\\\hline
          3\\\hline
          7\\\hline
          6\\\hline
          1\\\hline                                                                                                                               
          5\\\hline
          4\\\hline
      \end{tabular}&
\tikzmark{col2}
      \begin{tabular}{|c|}\hline
          \tikzmark{elem2}4\\\hline
          2\\\hline
          1\\\hline
          3\\\hline
          6\\\hline
          7\\\hline
          5\\\hline
      \end{tabular}&
\tikzmark{mat}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
1&0&1&0\\\hline
1&0&0&1\\\hline
0&1&0&1\\\hline
0&1&0&1\\\hline
0&1&0&1\\\hline
1&0&1&0\\\hline
1&0&1&0\\\hline
    \end{tabular}&
\tikzmark{sigMat}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\tikzmark{elem3}2&1&2&1\\\hline
2&1&4&1\\\hline                                                                                                                                   
1&2&1&2\\\hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\node [above=.01cm of col2] {\tiny Text Above columns};
\node[above=.01cm of mat] {\tiny Above 1st matrix};
\node[above=.1cm of sigMat]{\tiny Above 2nd matrix};

\node[above=2cm of mat,text width=6cm] (txt1) {Arrows go from here to...};

\path[draw,->] (txt1.south west) -- node {goes to 1st elem} (elem1);
\path[draw,->] (txt1.south) -- node {goes to 2nd elem} (elem2);
\path[draw,->] (txt1.south east) -- node {goes to 3rd elem} (elem3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}                                                                                                                                       

\end{document}
```

This results in the following slide:

[image]

Comment: There is a specific library for that, `tikzmark`. And you place the marks at weird places, and the output is a result of this. Why did you put `\tikzmark{mat}` where you put it?

Comment: I put `\tikzmark{mat}` there to be a point referring to the 7x4 matrix.

Comment: The main issue is that you forgot `overlay` in the `tikzpicture`. It needs to become `\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is that you forgot `overlay` in your `tikzpicture`. However, this is also to inform you that there is the `tikzmark` library, with which you can make the tables nodes, and elements subnodes.

```
\documentclass{beamer}              % only frames
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning,matrix,fit,tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\tikzmarknode{col1}{\begin{tabular}{|c|}\hline
          \subnode{elem1}{2}\\\hline
          3\\\hline
          7\\\hline
          6\\\hline
          1\\\hline                                                                                                                               
          5\\\hline
          4\\\hline
      \end{tabular}}&
\tikzmarknode{col2}{\begin{tabular}{|c|}\hline
          \subnode{elem2}{4}\\\hline
          2\\\hline
          1\\\hline
          3\\\hline
          6\\\hline
          7\\\hline
          5\\\hline
      \end{tabular}}&
\tikzmarknode{col3}{\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
1&0&1&0\\\hline
1&0&0&1\\\hline
0&1&0&1\\\hline
0&1&0&1\\\hline
0&1&0&1\\\hline
1&0&1&0\\\hline
1&0&1&0\\\hline
    \end{tabular}}&
\tikzmarknode{sigMat}{\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\subnode{elem3}{2}&1&2&1\\\hline
2&1&4&1\\\hline                                                                                                                                   
1&2&1&2\\\hline
  \end{tabular}}
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
 \node[fit=(col1)(col2)(col3)](cols){};
 \node[above=.01cm of cols,font=\tiny] {Text Above columns};
 \node[above=.01cm of col1,font=\tiny] {Above 1st matrix};
 \node[above=.1cm of sigMat,font=\tiny]{Above 2nd matrix};
% 
 \node[above=1cm of cols.north east] (txt1) {Arrows go from here to\dots};
% 
 \path[draw,->] (txt1.south west) -- node[sloped,font=\tiny,above] {goes to 1st elem} (elem1);
 \path[draw,->] (txt1.south) -- node[sloped,font=\tiny,above] {goes to 2nd elem} (elem2);
 \path[draw,->] (txt1.south east) -- node[sloped,font=\tiny,above] {goes to 3rd elem} (elem3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to build your code with xelatex and it puts arrows in slightly different places, outside columns and matrix. However, using lualatex it works well.

Comment: @MarcKees This is strange, but probably worth a separate question, which may be answered by some xelatex expert, which I am not.

Comment: I created a new question as you suggested: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505465/why-xelatex-renders-arrows-in-tikz-figures-differently-than-lualatex

Comment: @MarcKees I already upvoted it.