# Why xelatex renders arrows in tikz figures differently than lualatex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, luatex, tikzmark

My document can be produced with the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}              % only frames                                                                                                 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning,matrix,fit,tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\tikzmarknode{col1}{\begin{tabular}{|c|}\hline
\subnode{elem1}{2}\\\hline
3\\\hline
7\\\hline
6\\\hline
1\\\hline                                                                                                                               
5\\\hline
4\\\hline
\end{tabular}}&
\tikzmarknode{col2}{\begin{tabular}{|c|}\hline
\subnode{elem2}{4}\\\hline
2\\\hline
1\\\hline
3\\\hline
6\\\hline
7\\\hline
5\\\hline
\end{tabular}}&
\tikzmarknode{col3}{\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
1&0&1&0\\\hline
1&0&0&1\\\hline
0&1&0&1\\\hline
0&1&0&1\\\hline
0&1&0&1\\\hline
1&0&1&0\\\hline
1&0&1&0\\\hline
\end{tabular}}&
\tikzmarknode{sigMat}{\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\subnode{elem3}{2}&1&2&1\\\hline
2&1&4&1\\\hline                                                                                                                                   
1&2&1&2\\\hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[fit=(col1)(col2)(col3)](cols){};
\node[above=.01cm of cols,font=\tiny] {Text Above columns};
\node[above=.01cm of col1,font=\tiny] {Above 1st matrix};
\node[above=.1cm of sigMat,font=\tiny]{Above 2nd matrix};
% 
\node[above=1cm of cols.north east] (txt1) {Arrows go from here to\dots};
%                                                                                                                                                 
\path[draw,->] (txt1.south west) -- node[sloped,font=\tiny,above] {goes to 1st elem} (elem1);
\path[draw,->] (txt1.south) -- node[sloped,font=\tiny,above] {goes to 2nd elem} (elem2);
\path[draw,->] (txt1.south east) -- node[sloped,font=\tiny,above] {goes to 3rd elem} (elem3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

With lualatex, this code (compiled twice with lualatex example.tex) produces the following slide:

[image: lulatex results]

With xelatex, I get:
[image: xelatex results]

In this small example, the differences are small. But xelatex produced a very weird figure for a more complex code. pdflatex output is the same as lualatex.

Why there is such difference between lualatex and xelatex rendering?

Comment: Imho tikzmark is still broken for xelatex, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229500/tikzmark-and-xelatex

Comment: @UlrikeFischer your comment sounds like an answer

Comment: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/353

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to comments to the original question and 
github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/353, there is a bug in xelatex.