# Colored box from page limit to the end of chapter title in toc

Tags: table-of-contents, color, box

I'd like to have colored boxes around the titles in my toc. The box should begin at the edge of the page and finish after the end of the chapter name.

I found many solutions for having a box going from the chapter number to the page number. However, I couldn't find one corresponding to my need.

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:
[image: Exemple of Content section with chapter title in boxes going from edge of page to end of title]

Nb : due to font integration issues, I am using XeLatex.

## edit

As mentioned before, I need to use XeLatex for unicode support. Hence, Tikz are not a good solution as tikzmark and pgfmark are not well supported (as per [Why xelatex renders arrows in tikz figures differently than lualatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505465/why-xelatex-renders-arrows-in-tikz-figures-differently-than-lualatex) and my many many trials).

I managed to get something working partially:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt, american]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tocloft,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gettikzxy}[3]{%
  \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
  \edef#2{\the\pgf@x}%
  \edef#3{\the\pgf@y}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\tikzcoordinate}[1]{%
    \tikz[remember picture, overlay] \coordinate (#1);}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{%
    \tikzcoordinate{A}
    \bfseries\Large%
}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{%
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{%
    \coordinate (C);%
    \coordinate (B) at (current page.west|- A);
    \gettikzxy{(A)}{\ax}{\ay}
    \gettikzxy{(B)}{\bx}{\by}
    \gettikzxy{(C)}{\cx}{\cy}
    \fill[red,opacity=.2] ([yshift=+1.3333em,xshift=-.3333em]B) rectangle
                                    ([xshift=.3333em,yshift=+-1ex]C |- 0,0);
    \ifx\by\cy
    \else
        \coordinate (D) at (\cx+.3333em,\by+1.3333em);
        \coordinate (E) at (\ax-.8em+\linewidth- \cftchapindent- \cftchapnumwidth,\cy+1em);
        \gettikzxy{(D)}{\dx}{\dy}
        \gettikzxy{(E)}{\ex}{\ey}
        \ifdim\dx<\ex
            \fill[red,opacity=.2] (D) rectangle (E);
        \else
            \fill[white,opacity=1] (D) rectangle (E);
        \fi
    \fi
  }%
  \bfseries\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}%
}



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{(title chapter 1)}

\section{(title section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\section{(title section 2)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\chapter{(veryvery very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long title chapter 2)}
\section{(title section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\section{(title section 2)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\chapter{(very very very very very very very very long title chapter 3)}
\section{(title section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\section{(title section 2)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\end{document}
```

Which produces:
[image]

Now, my problem is that I need the color to be on the background to allow the text to be written in white on top of it.
Any clue on how to do that with XeLatex ?

Comment: Take one of the solutions using tikz and add an extension to `(current page.west)`.  A solution using tikzmark will already use `[remember picture,overlay]`.  Otherwise you may need `pgfinterruptboundingbox`/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found a solution. Issue in using tikzmark was not XeLatex. However, a counter has to be used to ensure that each mark name is unique. There is probably a simpler solution but this one is working fine.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gettikzxy}[3]{%
  \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
  \edef#2{\the\pgf@x}%
  \edef#3{\the\pgf@y}%
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{chapmarkcounter}
\setcounter{chapmarkcounter}{1}

\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{%
    \def\markname{cs:cmark:\expandafter\thechapmarkcounter}%
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{%
        \coordinate (A);%
        \coordinate (B) at (current page.west|- A);%
        \coordinate (C) at (pic \expandafter\markname);%
        \gettikzxy{(A)}{\ax}{\ay}%
        \gettikzxy{(B)}{\bx}{\by}%
        \gettikzxy{(C)}{\cx}{\cy}%
        \fill[red] (\bx-.3333em, \by+1.3333em) rectangle (\cx + .3333em, \cy-0.9ex);%
        \ifx\by\cy%
        \else%
            \coordinate (D) at (\cx+.3333em,\by+1.3333em);%
            \coordinate (E) at (\ax-.8em+\linewidth- \cftchapindent- \cftchapnumwidth,\cy+1em);%
            \gettikzxy{(D)}{\dx}{\dy}%
            \gettikzxy{(E)}{\ex}{\ey}%
            \ifdim\dx<\ex%
                \fill[red] (D) rectangle (E);%
            \else%
                \fill[white] (D) rectangle (E);%
            \fi%
        \fi%
    }%
    \color{white}\bfseries\Large%
}

\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{%
    \pgfmark{cmark:\expandafter\thechapmarkcounter}%
    \addtocounter{chapmarkcounter}{1}%
    \bfseries\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{(title chapter 1)}
\section{(title section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\section{(title section 2)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\chapter{(veryvery very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long title chapter 2)}
\section{(title section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\section{(title section 2)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\chapter{(very very very very very very very very long title chapter 3)}
\section{(title section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\section{(title section 2)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\chapter{(title chapter 4)}
\section{(title section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\section{(title section 2)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\end{document}
```

[image]